# Are created Bitmap scaled despite having the original one they are cut from unscaled?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code I use to cut a sprite(Bitmap variable) into several frames :

```
public void drawFrame(Canvas canvas, int frameIndex, int x, int y){
    int nbFramePerRow =  data.getWidth() / frameWidth;

    int sourceFrameY = frameIndex / nbFramePerRow;
    int sourceFrameX = frameIndex - (sourceFrameY * nbFramePerRow);

    sourceFrameX *= frameWidth;
    sourceFrameY *= frameWidth;

    int sourceFrameX2 = sourceFrameX + frameWidth;
    int sourceFrameY2 = sourceFrameY + frameHeight;

    int x2 = x + frameWidth;
    int y2 = y + frameHeight;

    Rect src = new Rect(sourceFrameX, sourceFrameY, sourceFrameX2, sourceFrameY2);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x2, y2);

    canvas.drawBitmap(data, src, dst, paint);
}
```

When I put my image in drawable, both(original and cut image) are unscaled. 
When I put it in no-dpi fodler they are both scaled(this is weird, should be the reverse...).

**Problem :** Looks like the pixels of unscaled and scaled cut image is different but the size of the frame in itself remain the same for both.
Which result in seeing only a portion of what I want to display when it's unscaled. **I want to display the cut image unscaled like the original.**

Comment: is your image inside the folder `res/drawable-nodpi`? if not, put it there...

Comment: did you try putting them in `res/raw` ?\

Comment: @Shark When I do, the image is fully displayed but it is scaled.

Comment: I updated the post. I made a clearer explanation (I tried ha ha)

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
drawable-nodpi
```

the images aren't scaled. If you place them in any other folder, they are treated as if they are made for a given density, and will be scaled to fit other densities.

PLease note that if you use Android Studio and use the ANdroid view, all drawables will appear to be in drawable and look like

```
|
|- Drawable
|-- someimage.png (mdpi)
|-- someimageother.png(idpi)
|-- somethirdimage.png
```

if it says a given folder after it is in a different drawable folder.

So have you checked to make sure it actually is in `drawable` and not some other folder? Switch to `project` view to check it, or check after the drawable name. You can also open it in a file browser for whatever OS you are using and check like that

---

If you by scaling mean the image becomes smaller/bigger with density, that is expected when the size is the same. Assuming you have a 256x256 image, it looks bigger on lower densities, and smaller on higher densities

Comment: In drawable my image appears non scaled, can't tell you why tho.

Comment: If it is in drawable-nodpi you tell the system it isn't designed for a specific density and should have the same size on all densities

Comment: Maybe my installation is corrupted I don't know. When I put files in drawable they aren't scaled. What can I tell you ><

Comment: So you want them to be scaled?

Comment: No I want my frame to not being scaled (like the original one)

Comment: Is your canvas being scaled?

Comment: Canvas can be scaled ? I can't tell you. I can draw unscaled images without problems. Even the cut images seems unscaled but : it's like it was displayed into a tiny square so I can only see a part of them.

Comment: Canvas can be scaled using a matrix, but also using two floats. If you are doing that somewhere and not undoing it, that would explain why it is scaled

Comment: I only use `canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` and `drawBitmap`. Is there any hidden scaling in them ?

Comment: unless you specifically call the method, it isn't scaled. And I think I just figured out what you meant

Answer (score 0):

It's ok for the bitmap to be scaled. It's done to avoid memory leaks on devices with small RAM when loading many of huge pictures. You just need to feagure what the dencity of the screen is by using

```
Resources#getDisplayMetrics()#density
```

The values are:

0.75 - ldpi

1.0 - mdpi

1.5 - hdpi

2.0 - xhdpi

3.0 - xxhdpi

4.0 - xxxhdpi

Then you just need to apply the scaling to your animation frames size calculation

Comment: When I draw image I prevent them from being scaled. But it doesn't work when I draw Image I cut from the original. I want the cut ones to not be scaled too.